# Override CSS style behaviour without using !important or inline style sheet

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i am facing issue of css override.   below css are applied on textbox(with class xdTextBox )

```
          .xdTextBox   {
            padding:1px;
            line-height:10px; 
            border:2px #cc0 solid;
```

}

```
     input[type="text"]  {
          padding:10px;
          margin:10px;
          line-height:15px; 
          border:none;
```

}

I want Result as textbox with  padding:1px, line-height:10px,  border:2px #cc0 solid;

I can't  use !important or inline stylesheet

is it possible ? please suggest your solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The general idea of making something more prioritized is to add more specific selectors to it.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="xdTextBox" name="exmapleInput" />
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="text"].xdTextBox {
    padding:1px;
    line-height:10px; 
    border:2px #cc0 solid;    
}
```

For further reading: [Reviewing CSS style priority](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/)

Comment: No, a class is not more prioritized.

Comment: @Pinocchio: A class selector is equally specific with an attribute selector and they are both more specific than a type selector.

Comment: @BoltClock I meant a class wont over-ride `input[type="text"]`

Comment: @Pinocchio Thanks. Updated (although the first answer was still right)

Comment: @Itay Well, no. As BoltClock Said classes are not more prioritized, they are equal

Comment: But `input[type="text"].xdTextBox` is still more specific than `input[type="text"]`

Comment: Yes, I know. You said you think classes are more important than attribute selectors.

Comment: This is the part I fixed. When I said the first answer was still right I was regarding to the code.

Answer (score 1):

A class selector has a lower specifity than a tag and attribute selector - see [**Calculating a selector's specificity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)

You still have several options to overwrite the browsers default styles - one has @Itay already posted.

As always your selector needs a higher specifity or if it is equal it has to come after in the stylesheet (which automatically is the fact in case of browser default styles).

And just one word concerning your desired styles: What font-size will you use that you set the `line-height` to 10px!? Anyway, always set the font-size and the line-height as an unitless value (multiplyer for the font-size).